# Enable async rendering in react 16

Tags: reactjs, react-fiber

React 16 brings a new [core architecture](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-core-architecture). They worked on a new mechanism of async rendering which might make the animation more fluid. But async rendering is not yet enabled.

I have some performance issues with a react application in firefox. I would to try if enabling async rendering could help.

**How can i enable async rendering in react 16 ?**

Answer (score 4):

This was on the website you've mentioned in your Question:

> We think async rendering is a big deal, and represents the future of React. To make migration to v16.0 as smooth as possible, we’re not enabling any async features yet, but we’re excited to start rolling them out in the coming months. Stay tuned!

I guess you'll have to wait a while ^^

Answer (score 1):

Any such thing - you can do so via enabling/disabling flags from feature flags file in react source code.

Example - https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.5.2/packages/shared/ReactFeatureFlags.js#L17

Example for if you want to enable latest Hooks feature in React:
https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/13968/files#diff-904ceabd8a1e9a07ab1d876d843d62e1R12